# How to update table value based on the time line

Tags: java, mysql, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Can anyone please suggest me the best approach for my requirement? I need to automatically update the table value after some specified time, using Java and MySQL as the database.

Comment: may be you should check for API's like quartz sheduler

Comment: @sanbhat: his requirement doesn't need quartz :)

Comment: @viny : The OP has not specified enough details for us to be sure that the requirement "doesn't need quartz" .

Comment: this is very wide question. But in general if you look just for course of action, I would create single thread counting seconds and after it crosses specified interval, it creates SQL query and updates your record in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a timer in Java.
2. Add a task to timer that updates value to MySQL.
3. Start timer

Example of Java Timer API: [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-timer/)

Comment: As for a timer, he could for example look at... Quartz?

Answer (score 1):

Using Quartz scheduler you can achieve this. You need to create one job and run that job at the required time so that it will fetch the data from the database and according to that you will do what's needed.

[Quartz Scheduler Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/)

Comment: +1 - Quartz would be a very flexible option.
Can be adapted to various types of needs and has easy framework integration.